# Setting a cookie for sidebar toggled display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I did not make this javascript, but i am trying to edit it to include a cookie for the toggle status of the whole sidebar rather than just the div inside the sidebar any help? i suck at JS and this is all jibberish to me.

```
    vB_XHTML_Ready.subscribe(init_sidebar);
function init_sidebar() {
    new vBSidebar()
}
function vBSidebar() {
    this.init()
}
vBSidebar.prototype.init = function() {
    this.sidebar_button = YAHOO.util.Dom.get("sidebar_button");
    this.sidebar_container = YAHOO.util.Dom.get("sidebar_container");
    this.sidebar = YAHOO.util.Dom.get("sidebar");
    this.content_container = YAHOO.util.Dom.get("content_container");
    this.content = YAHOO.util.Dom.get("content");
    YAHOO.util.Event.on(this.sidebar_button, "click", this.toggle_collapse, this, true)
};
vBSidebar.prototype.toggle_collapse = function(A) {
    YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(A);
    if (YAHOO.util.Dom.getStyle(this.sidebar, "display") == "none") {
        this.expand()
    } else {
        this.collapse(true)
    }
    return false
};
vBSidebar.prototype.collapse = function(A) {
    var B = this.sidebar_button;
    if (A) {
        var C = new YAHOO.util.Anim(this.sidebar, {
            opacity: {
                from: 1,
                to: 0
            }
        }, 0.3);
        C.onComplete.subscribe(function(G, D, E) {
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(E.sidebar, "display", "none");
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(E.sidebar_container, "width", "0");
            var F;
            if (sidebar_align == "right") {
                F = new YAHOO.util.Anim(E.content_container, {
                    marginRight: {
                        to: 0
                    }
                }, 0.3);
                F.animate();
                F = new YAHOO.util.Anim(E.content, {
                    marginRight: {
                        to: 0
                    }
                }, 0.3);
                F.onComplete.subscribe(function() {
                    YAHOO.util.Dom.setAttribute(B, "src", IMGDIR_MISC + "/tab-expanded.png")
                });
                F.animate()
            } else {
                F = new YAHOO.util.Anim(E.content_container, {
                    marginLeft: {
                        to: 0
                    }
                }, 0.3);
                F.animate();
                F = new YAHOO.util.Anim(E.content, {
                    marginLeft: {
                        to: 0
                    }
                }, 0.3);
                F.onComplete.subscribe(function() {
                    YAHOO.util.Dom.setAttribute(B, "src", IMGDIR_MISC + "/tab-expanded-left.png")
                });
                F.animate()
            }
        }, this);
        C.animate()
    } else {
        YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(this.sidebar, "display", "none");
        YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(this.sidebar_container, "width", "0");
        if (sidebar_align == "right") {
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setAttribute(B, "src", IMGDIR_MISC + "/tab-expanded.png");
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(this.content_container, "marginRight", "0");
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(this.content, "marginRight", "0")
        } else {
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setAttribute(B, "src", IMGDIR_MISC + "/tab-expanded-left.png");
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(this.content_container, "marginLeft", "0");
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(this.content, "marginLeft", "0")
        }
    }
    this.save_collapsed("1")
};
vBSidebar.prototype.expand = function() {
    var B;
    var A = this.sidebar_button;
    if (sidebar_align == "right") {
        B = new YAHOO.util.Anim(this.content_container, {
            marginRight: {
                to: (0 - content_container_margin)
            }
        }, 0.3);
        B.animate();
        B = new YAHOO.util.Anim(this.content, {
            marginRight: {
                to: content_container_margin
            }
        }, 0.3);
        B.onComplete.subscribe(function(F, C, D) {
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(D.sidebar, "display", "block");
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(D.sidebar_container, "width", sidebar_width + "px");
            var E = new YAHOO.util.Anim(D.sidebar, {
                opacity: {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 1
                }
            }, 0.3);
            E.onComplete.subscribe(function() {
                YAHOO.util.Dom.setAttribute(A, "src", IMGDIR_MISC + "/tab-collapsed.png")
            });
            E.animate()
        }, this);
        B.animate()
    } else {
        B = new YAHOO.util.Anim(this.content_container, {
            marginLeft: {
                to: (0 - content_container_margin)
            }
        }, 0.3);
        B.animate();
        B = new YAHOO.util.Anim(this.content, {
            marginLeft: {
                to: content_container_margin
            }
        }, 0.3);
        B.onComplete.subscribe(function(F, C, D) {
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(D.sidebar, "display", "block");
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(D.sidebar_container, "width", sidebar_width + "px");
            var E = new YAHOO.util.Anim(D.sidebar, {
                opacity: {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 1
                }
            }, 0.3);
            E.onComplete.subscribe(function() {
                YAHOO.util.Dom.setAttribute(A, "src", IMGDIR_MISC + "/tab-collapsed-left.png")
            });
            E.animate()
        }, this);
        B.animate()
    }
    this.save_collapsed("0")
};
vBSidebar.prototype.save_collapsed = function(A) {
    expires = new Date();
    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1000 * 86400 * 365));
    set_cookie("vbulletin_sidebar_collapse", A, expires)
};
```

at the very end i see the set cookie... but its not right, that cookie sets the status of the

`<div class="block smaller">`

and i want it to set the status of the

```
<ul id="sidebar">
```

the complete body looks like:

```
<body>
<div class="body_wrapper">


    <div id="content_container" class=" ">
        <div id="content" >

    <!-- main -->

    <ol id="forums" class="floatcontainer">
        <li class="forumbit_nopost old L1" id="cat1">
    <div class="forumhead foruminfo L1 collapse">
        <h2>
            <center>Content Content Content </center>
        </h2>
    </div>
</li>
    </ol>

    <!-- /main -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar_container" class="">

<div class="clear"></div>

        <a id="sidebar_button_link" href="#">

            <img id="sidebar_button" src="images/misc/tab-collapsed.png" alt="" />

        </a>
        <ul id="sidebar"  >
            <li>
    <div class="block smaller">
        <div class="blocksubhead">
            <a class="collapse" id="collapse_block_html_3" href="#top"><img alt="" src="images/misc/collapse_40b.png" id="collapseimg_html_3"/></a>
            <span class="blocktitle">Sidebar</span>
        </div>
        <div class="widget_content blockbody floatcontainer">
        <div id="block_html_3" class="blockrow">
            Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="underblock"></div>
</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


<div style="clear:both;"></div>


<div id="footer" class="floatcontainer footer">

FOOTER

</div>
</div> 

</body>
```

sorry for not making a JSFiddle, but it would not run in JSFiddle, you can see a live example of what i have though at http://dirtrif.com/index.php?styleid=9

Comment: Why use a cookie? Just use node or backbone js.

Comment: @StuartWickenden will either of those remember if the sidebar is collapsed or not on each page load?

Comment: Backbone is specifically designed to remember its state. It works without page refreshes and is best used with `AJAX` for dynamic population of content. It's ideal for the type of thing you have illustrated at your link.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to achieve here. A nice quick solution for you which would be considerably quicker as well would be to use local storage.

All you would have to do is when the sidebar is hidden a local storage item is set to 1 and then when it is shown it is set to 0.

On page load you could just run a quick simple if statement to check the value of the local storage item and then to show according to what its value is.

I hope this helps!